# JMeter export graph to CSV exports to multiple columns, write results to file exports to one column

Tags: jmeter

I was annoyed with JMeter writing data results to CSV as one column. So when the CSV file was opened in Excel all values would be added to one single column (which requires annoying manual copy/paste work to get to graphs). I then noticed that if I choose Export to CSV on a Listener graph, it actually exports the CSV file as separate columns in Excel, which is great.

Is it possible to have the "Write results to file" write data into separate columns by default as it does with the graph "Export to CSV"? Thanks!

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have at least 2 options:

1. [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer), which one you are using at the moment, as you understand.
   In `jmeter.properties` file (`JMETER_HOME\bin\jmeter.properties`) uncomment and set `jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=;` to use ';' instead of ',' (used by default) as separator in csv-files (which one you are creating using "Write results to file") - this will separate values in different columns if opened in Excel.

   ```
   # For use with Comma-separated value (CSV) files or other formats
   # where the fields' values are separated by specified delimiters.
   jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=;
   ```
2. [Flexible File Writer](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter) from [jmeter-plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) pack implments the same functionality and looks to be more customizable.
   Idea is the same as above - use ";" to separate values written into file:

   ```
   Write file header: endTimeMillis;responseTime;latency;sentBytes;receivedBytes;isSuccessful;responseCode
   Record each sample as: endTimeMillis|;|responseTime|;|latency|;|sentBytes|;|receivedBytes|;|isSuccessful|;|responseCode|\r\n
   ```

Hope this helps.